# Custom JSON Serialization & Deserialization

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson

I have a JSON where I do not yet know what concrete parameters it could contain. Without this I cannot use the annotations that would do the serialization & de-serialization out of the box. For example., for the following JSON:

```
{
....
....
DynamicField : {
 "field1" : { }
 "field2" : {
   "url" : "some url"
   "something" : "Something else"
  } 
...
...
}
```

How can I now properly serialize and de-serialize the DynamicField? I'm using the faster jackson library.

Comment: JSON of arbitrary complexity/structure can always be represented as a set of Maps and Lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` with a output type of `java.util.Map`.  That will give you a nested hierarchy of `Map[String, Object]` matching the input.  For example,

```
val nestedMaps = mapper.readValue(json, classOf([java.util.Map])
```